# Linux Crypto API SHA1

Tags: linux, api, cryptography, kernel, sha1

I'm trying to compute a sha1 hash inside a kernel module using Linux Crypto APIs, but I can't find information on how to set up the scatter list used by the async request. Also, how should I wait for the async operation to complete?

```
static int plaintext_to_sha1(void) {

    struct scatterlist sg[8];
    struct crypto_ahash *tfm;
    struct ahash_request *req;

    char *plaintext = "TEST!\0";
    unsigned char *result = kmalloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * SHA1_LENGTH, GFP_KERNEL);
    unsigned int len = strlen(plaintext);

    tfm = crypto_alloc_ahash("sha1", 0, CRYPTO_ALG_ASYNC);
    if (IS_ERR(tfm)) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "tfm allocation failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* ... set up the scatterlists ... */

    req = ahash_request_alloc(tfm, GFP_ATOMIC);
    if (!req) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "request allocation failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ahash_request_set_callback(req, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ahash_request_set_crypt(req, sg, result, 2);

    if (crypto_ahash_digest(req)) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "digest failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ahash_request_free(req);
    crypto_free_ahash(tfm);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It almost sounds like it would be easier to avoid the async task. Looking at the use of SHA in [`random.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/char/random.c), a synchronous hash is used rather than an asynchronous one. `sha_init` and `sha_transform` are called directly using an appropriately defined inline structure.

Comment: That function only hash 512 bit of data as stated in the sha1.c file (This function generates a SHA1 digest for a single 512-bit block.). I need a way to hash a larger chunk of data. Looking in the crypto APIs there is also a synchronous API. Do you suggest using that?

Comment: SHA-1 isn't protected against length extension attacks *because* SHA-1 is just hashings blocks + padding + length indicator. Most hardware doesn't have SHA-1 speedup (it's pretty fast all by itself) so you can basically use any low level SHA-1 library - why do you need kernel level support?